# How to see rake task puts / logs inside rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I've one rake task like this:

```
task :create_orders, [:my_param] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "hello"
    Rails.logger.debug "hey"
end
```

When I called the rake task from a button inside my view, everything inside the rake task run like what I want.

But, I can't see what I've put inside the `puts` and `Rails.logger.debug` inside my terminal where I run the `rails server` command to start the localhost server.

I also try to run `tail -f log/development.log` inside my project folder but nothing `puts` or `Rails.logger.debug` statements from my rake task showing up.

What should I do so that I can see what I've put inside `puts` and `Rails.logger.debug` statements inside my `rails server` terminal?

Comment: How do you call rake task?

Comment: Using AJAX. The AJAX url to a route inside my controller. I have this inside my controller action: `%x(bundle exec rake create_orders)`

Comment: That’s the answer. `%x` runs a command in a subshell. To share application resources one should call rake tasks with `Rake::Task[...].invoke`.

Comment: The problem is, when I use `Rake::Task[...].invoke`, I always get this error `NameError (uninitialized constant MyController::Rake)` which results my rake task not running at all.

Comment: Only inside the action or at the very top of the controller?

Comment: Ok, I put it on very top of my controller. Now I get this error: `RuntimeError (Don't know how to build task 'create_orders')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this on very top of my controller:

```
require 'rake'
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

And inside the action that calling the rake task, I replaced `%x(bundle exec rake task_name)` with `Rake::Task["task_name"].invoke`.

Thanks mudasobwa for the help!